# Ubuntu 16.04 with Nvidia 750ti breaks every time: blinking cursor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation, graphics

Ok, I've been messing with this for hours now.  I've read lots of forums and getting nowhere. Here's what happens.  As soon as I install the Nvidia drivers and reboot, The PC boots to a blinking cursor in the upper left corner and nothing else.  I read all over to `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` or other things to uninstall the drivers, but I can't get to a terminal to do any of this.

When it's sitting at this blinking cursor, I've tried holding down Ctrl+Alt+ and hitting any and all of the F1-F12 keys.  Nothing.  I've tried holding down the Shift key on boot and same... nothing.  I've tried to boot the live CD but all I can see on the live CD is the CD contents, not the hard drive, so I'm just configuring the CD's OS.

First, how do I go about fixing an install after a corrupt Nvidia install, for starters.  (I'm sure my next attempt will fail and I'd rather not reinstall again.)

Second, how do I go about installing Nvidia drivers for a GeForce 750ti desktop graphics card?

Here are the last steps I tried which failed with the same result.

```
sudo apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
-type sudo apt get-install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

I read somewhere that maybe the onboard graphics are conflicting, so it suggests to update those. Maybe I should purge them? I don't know.

Comment: I suggest you avoiding that ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa repository and use the proprietary  Nvidia drivers from the main Xenial repository. The problems I had with the edgers broke my install every time I updated the system.

Comment: It looks like you did a lot of wrong things. I suggest re-installing the system, then you need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS and run `sudo apt install nvidia-367`. That easy.

Comment: I just did a clean install with a disabled secure boot in the bios.  After the clean install, the first and only command I ran was "sudo apt install nvidia-367" and rebooted.  System is sitting at a blinking cursor and doesn't boot.  My system is "bricked" again.

Answer (score 0):

so, I just did these steps and still broke my computer where it doesn't boot again... just the blinking cursor after reboot.

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nouveau.blacklist=1 /g' /etc/default/grub

sudo update-grub
```

after rebooted, graphics really bad.

1. `sudo gdm service stop` or `sudo service lightdm stop`
2. sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-334.21.run
3. it give you some warning on pre build script I have continued
4. it ask you to accept some condition, you give all yes
5. let it change `xorg.profile` for you

The install went exactly as described.  But reboot and the PC is "bricked."  Cant get into a recovery mode and cant do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> key to get to a command line.

Comment: Please do not add information in answer boxes. You can edit your question.